# "npm audit" adds more vulnerabilities to electron react project

Tags: node.js, npm

In my ubuntu terminal, I am running nvm node.js version v20.3.1 (the most up to date) where I have cloned my github project https://github.com/MartinBarker/rendertune-react-dev/tree/dev

When I run `npm i` and `npm audit` in my project, I see `74 moderate vulnerabilities`

```
74 moderate severity vulnerabilities

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

So I think I will run `npm audit` to fix these issues. I run `npm audit` and it still says 74 vulnerabilities so none were fixed, but the messages say that `npm audit fix --force` will fix these issues:

```
$ npm audit
# npm audit report

semver  <7.5.2
Severity: moderate
semver vulnerable to Regular Expression Denial of Service - https://github.com/advisories/GHSA-c2qf-rxjj-qqgw
fix available via `npm audit fix --force`
Will install electron-builder@23.4.0, which is a breaking change
node_modules/semver
node_modules/simple-update-notifier/node_modules/semver
  @babel/core  *
  Depends on vulnerable versions of @babel/helper-compilation-targets
  Depends on vulnerable versions of semver
  node_modules/@babel/core

...
74 moderate severity vulnerabilities
```

so I run `npm audit fix --force` and then that brings my issue count up way way higher

```
162 vulnerabilities (10 low, 108 moderate, 36 high, 8 critical)

To address issues that do not require attention, run:
  npm audit fix

To address all issues possible (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Some issues need review, and may require choosing
a different dependency.
```

Am i using npm audit correctly? Is there some way I can remove the 74 vulnerabilities? I really dont want any vulnerabilities present, is that unavoidable?